# color a row in html?

Tags: visualforce, html

I want to set the background color of this row to #C0C0C0 how do i do that? When i do it on the  attribute i get a line between the label and the data. when i add it to the  nothing happens. i think there's something going on between what i'm trying to do and the css  and span multiple lines?

```
                 <table width="100%" >    <tr><td BGCOLOR="#2d97cc" ALIGN="center"> Updates</td></tr> </table>
                <table class="sub_section"> <tr>  <td class="mysub_section_label">q1</td>   <td class="sub_section_data"> {!c.q1__c}</td> </tr></table>
                <table class="sub_section"> <tr>  <td class="mysub_section_label">q2:</td>   <td class="sub_section_data"> {!c.q2__c}</td> </tr></table>
                <table class="sub_section"> <tr>  <td class="mysub_section_label">q3:</td>   <td class="sub_section_data"> {!c.q3__c}</td> </tr></table>
                <table class="sub_section"> <tr>  <td class="mysub_section_label">q4:</td>     <td class="sub_section_data"> {!c.q4__c}</td> </tr></table>
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about borders, margins and padding in HTML tables and how styles are applied to them.

Comment: hmm- yea, you're right. my bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the style on the tr tag.

```
<tr style="background: #c0c0c0">
```

Comment: i did that, but it's not spanning multiple <trs> (there's a gap) basically for that section i want it to be that background. Do i need to  make a div and set the style background there?

Comment: That is because of cell spacing - http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_table_cellspacing - Make your cell spacing 0 if you don't want a gap.

Comment: If you want the entire table background set, set it on the table or tbody. There's a difference between coloring a cell, a row, and a table. Of course, if your intent is to use alternating row colors, cell spacing is important, too.

Comment: @JesseAltman [w3fools](http://www.w3fools.com/) recommends that you avoid quoting w3schools due to the mis-information they tend to spread, their lack of responsiveness in regards to errors on the site, etc. Stick with the [World Wide Web Consortium](http://www.w3c.org/) or the [Mozilla Developer Network](http://developer.mozilla.org/).

Answer (score 1):

You can style the tables e.g. using a `style` element:

```
<style>
tr { background: #c0c0c0 }
table { border-spacing: 0 3px }
</style>
```

The second rule sets horizontal spacing between cells to zero but vertical spacing to 3 pixels. Tune as desired.